# Firefox get different render for dropdown using material design lite

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Firefox browser (linux and widows) false render dropdown. I've try in chrome (linux and windows) and edge, they render it correctly.
Demo: [`here`](http://codepen.io/3mp3ri0r/pen/bpPWax)

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @RDC. Thanks for reply. I've provide the demo code in codepen. Watch carefully. Or maybe you can't see the link? Here again: http://codepen.io/3mp3ri0r/pen/bpPWax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to `.mos-selectfield`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKqwQY

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks dude.